# Quiero que al hacer click al botón se escriba la etiqueta <b></b> dentro del textarea

Tags: javascript, html

Tengo un `textarea` y un botón, pero resulta que cuando hago click en el botón para que me escriba la etiqueta de apertura y de cierre de la etiqueta  de HTML5, si hay texto dentro del `textarea` ignora la orden, pero si no existe texto dentro del `textarea` este escribe la etiqueta correctamente pero solo lo hace una vez, y yo quiero que lo haga todas las veces que yo haga click en el botón

**Código HTML5 del textarea y botón:**

```
<!-- Cuerpo -->
                        <div class="input-field col s12">
                            <i class="material-icons prefix grey-text">web</i>
                            <textarea id="cuerpo" name="cuerpo" class="materialize-textarea" required></textarea>
                            <label for="cuerpo">Cuerpo de la noticia</label>
                            <span class="helper-text" data-error="wrong" data-success="right">

                            <button id="b" type="button" class="waves-effect green btn">B
                            </button>

                            </span>
                        </div>
```

**Código JavaScript:**

```
var cuerpo = document.querySelector('#cuerpo');
var parrafo = document.querySelector('#p');
var strong = document.querySelector('#strong');
var b = document.querySelector('#b');

b.addEventListener('click', () => {

    cuerpo.innerHTML = "<b></b>";
    console.log('Has dado click a la '+b);

});
```

Quiero intentar hacer mas o menos lo mismo que hay en ese foro, para lograr colocar etiquetas de HTML5 dentro del contenido del texto.

Comment: Por lo que se, los textarea no admiten etiquetas html, corríjanme si me equivoco.

Comment: El tag en el text area solo se vería el texto plano. Para que acumule el valor y agregue depués de escribir, puedes usar la propiedad value: cuerpo.value += "<b></b>";

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo que sucede es que solo lo hace una vez porque dentro de la función solo asignas `cuerpo.innerHTML += "<b></b>";`, por lo que siempre que se haga clic sobre el botón asignará el mismo valor, y si tienes texto previo este será sustituido por `<b></b>`. Así que solo basta con utilizar el operador [`+=`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Addition_assignment) para conservar el texto previo a agregar el texto de la etiqueta.

**Edit:** Adicionalmente es recomendable utilizar `.value` para elementos de un form en lugar de `.innerHTML`. `.innerHTML` se utiliza para elementos como div, span, td, y otros elementos similares.

```js
var cuerpo = document.querySelector('#cuerpo');
var parrafo = document.querySelector('#p');
var strong = document.querySelector('#strong');
var b = document.querySelector('#b');

b.addEventListener('click', () => {
  cuerpo.value += "<b></b>";
});
```

```html
<div class="input-field col s12">
    <i class="material-icons prefix grey-text">web</i>
    <textarea id="cuerpo" name="cuerpo" class="materialize-textarea" required></textarea>
    <label for="cuerpo">Cuerpo de la noticia</label>
    <span class="helper-text" data-error="wrong" data-success="right">
    <button id="b" type="button" class="waves-effect green btn">B
    </button>
    </span>
</div>
```

Comment: Ya lo he corregido, revisa mi edit.